LPDDR3 or DDR3L? And which SSD?
I have an old laptop, and I would like to upgrade its hardware. After some hours checking the manual, forums, and also contacting the laptop company. Discovered that the upgrades of easiest support are changing the RAM and replacing the HD by a SSD. So, firstly, I give some info about the laptop, and then I will describe the problems I am facing.

Product name: S14BW01;
Processor type: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz;
Memory: 4096 MB (LPDDR3 1600 MHz) (TEIKON 4 GB 1Rx8 PC3L-12800s-11-13-B4) (extensible till 8 GB);
HD: 500 GB BARRACUDA ST500LM030.

Precisely, I have the following questions.

When searching for "equivalently" improved RAM memories, I was able only to find DDR3L related, and no LPDDR3. Is there any issue with this?
Concerning the replacement of the HD to a SSD, I am totally lost. How can I find the requirements for my case?

Sorry if this question is not suitable for this sub, but the only others related stackexchange forums, were the electronics and retrocomputing. But I found this more related.

DDR3L is not quite the same as LPDDR3 but if your ssytem can take either then it makes no real difference. As long as you are replacing a SATA HDD with a SATA SSD you will see no functional difference but the speed difference will be immense.

Thank you so much. Is there any limit in terms of TB my setup can handle?

For the SSD/HDD? It's vaguely irrelevant. You could fit a 4TB HDD for a similar cost as a 1TB SSD and it wouldn't make any real difference except that the SSD will be a lot faster. And I mean a lot.

Thank you so much everyone. @Gantendo, yes less than that. #Mokubai thank you so much.

Update: Just made the replacements, and now it is way faster. Thxs guys!
